# Jrip output in weka

Tags: weka

I am conducting an comparative study on weka. Using some of evaluation criterias such as; the average number of conditions.

```
avg number of condition = number of conditions in the antecedent part / 
                          number of all generated rules
```

but i got the following output of JRIP algorithm:

```
(Wifes_education = 4) and (Number_of_children_ever_born >= 3) and (Wifes_age >= 34) and (Wifes_age <= 42) => Contraceptive_method_used=2 (141.0/56.0)
(Wifes_education = 4) and (Number_of_children_ever_born >= 3) and (Wifes_age >= 29) and (Wifes_age <= 48) and (Wifes_age >= 44) => Contraceptive_method_used=2 (53.0/24.0)
(Wifes_age <= 35) and (Number_of_children_ever_born >= 3) => Contraceptive_method_used=3 (377.0/171.0)
(Wifes_age <= 30) and (Number_of_children_ever_born >= 1) and (Wifes_age <= 22) => Contraceptive_method_used=3 (122.0/59.0)

**=> Contraceptive_method_used=1 (780.0/316.0)**
Number of Rules : 5
```

what about the last rule (bold rule)? its without antecedent part!
how can i obtain the number of conditions in the last rule?

Comment: how is it related to `HTML`?

Comment: Consider revising your question.

Answer (score 1):

The last rule (implicit) condition "captures" everything that has not been covered by the other rules. Its condition is "everything else".